# How to prove d is metric if prime number is involved?

Tags: metric-spaces

[image]

Please have a look at this question.
Can anyone please tell me how to approach when dp(x,y) /= 0?
Does this mean if x= y, then d=0, otherwise d = p^-k? or only if p^k satisfy the following condition? if so, does that mean d is not defined when the condition is not satisfied?

Or do I just need to find a  particular prime number?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You get one metric for each prime. $d_2$ is different from $d_3$ et cetera. What it means is that for example $d_2(1,5)=1/4$ because $5-1$ is divisible by four but not divisible by eight. But $d_3(1,5)=1$, because $5-1$ is not divisible by the prime three at all. Verifying that $d_2$ satisfies the triangle inequality amounts to proving that $$d_2(x,z)\le d_2(x,y)+d_2(y,z)$$ for all integer $x,y,z$. For example if $x=1$, $y=5$, $z=3$, then $d_2(x,z)=1/2=d_2(y,z)$, and the triangle inequality is satisfied because $1/2\le 1/2+1/4$.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/P-adic_Norm_is_Norm

Comment: Anyway, you should look at which powers of $p$ can divide the respective differences $x-y,x-z,y-z$.